# Visual Studio 2010 comment / uncomment buttons for css files

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010

Are there comment and uncomment buttons that work while you're editing a css file?

```
/* #content h2 {

    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;
} */
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can record your own macros in VS.

This article might help you (it's for VS2008 but it's same in VS2010):

http://www.brianschmitt.com/2009/09/how-to-comment-uncomment-code-selection.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I tried it out and it works pretty good. Why Microsoft couldn't implement this themselves in VS is beyond me. Even worse, I am ashamed that JetBrains didn't make ReSharper fix this obviously broken feature. *sigh

Comment: The link is dead now :( Possibly the links are updated to [how-to-comment-uncomment-code-selection](http://www.brianschmitt.com/how-to-comment-uncomment-code-selection/)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.

The regular comment keyboard shortcuts, `Ctrl+/` or `Ctrl+Shift+/` do not work in CSS files. I even have Resharper installed and it's "Comment with line comment" and "Comment with block comment" menu items are disabled while inside CSS file.

You may be able to set up your own custom macro and assign a keyboard shortcut. Or there may be a different plugin available which offers this functionality but it is certainly not build into the IDE.

Comment: Good to know.  Visual Studio could do a much better job at commands and shortcuts while working with css files.  I use NetBeans to work with PHP files (wordpress) and I noticed the css functionality in that IDE is a lot easier to use.  Power tools for css would be nice for VS.